# c++ [regex] how to extract given char value

Tags: c++, regex, string

how to extract digit number value?

```
std::regex legit_command("^\\([A-Z]+[0-9]+\\-[A-Z]+[0-9]+\\)$");
std::string input;
```

let say the user key in

```
(AA11-BB22)
```

i want get the

```
first_character = "aa"
first_number = 11
secondt_character = "bb"
second_number = 22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use capture groups. In the example below I replaced `(AA11+BB22)` with `(AA11-BB22)` to match the regex you posted. Note that [`regex_match`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) only succeeds if the *entire* string matches the pattern so the beginning/end of line assertions (`^` and `$`) are not required.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  const string input = "(AA11-BB22)";
  const regex legit_command("\\(([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)-([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)\\)");

  smatch matches;
  if(regex_match(input, matches, legit_command)) {
    cout << "first_character  " << matches[1] << endl;
    cout << "first_number     " << matches[2] << endl;
    cout << "second_character " << matches[3] << endl;
    cout << "second_number    " << matches[4] << endl;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
$ c++ main.cpp && ./a.out 
first_character  AA
first_number     11
second_character BB
second_number    22
```

Comment: Outside of a bracket expression/character class, a `-` is not any special and should not be escaped (hence my edit).

Comment: how to access matches[2] and matches[4] to convert them into int?

Comment: @user3770234 You can use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) for that. Note that it may throw an exception if the value is out of range for an int (the regex does not impose a length limit – you can do `[0-9]{2}` to require exactly two digits for example). `const int first_number = stoi(matches[2]);`

Comment: sorry for distrub, then how to convert A become number as 0, i trying to use matches[1] - 'A' will give int value